# I cannot access phpmyadmin

Tags: installation

I had install phpmyadmin, using this:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

after that, I wrote in URL:

```
http:/localhost/phpmyadmin
```

But it won't work. **NOT FOUND**, this error appear, so what to do? Any solution would be advisable :)

Comment: Did you really typed `http:/localhost/phpmyadmin`? It should be `http://localhost...`, with 2 slashes before localhost.

Comment: Also, please verify that phpmyadmin is indeed installed on your local machine and not somewhere else. Localhost only works for your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure about your web-server state in running or the php application is installed? if not you can do these for them:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status
```

and

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php5
```